# Paypal Website Payments Standard

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I'm really having trouble finding out how to set this up. Their documentation is horrendous at best. I called Paypal and told them what I need:

1. have my own custom shopping cart
2. client doesn't want to pay monthly fee

I was told that I could use Website Payments Standard to send my cart contents and the user can choose to sign in/pay or simply pay by CC without an account. Every link on their documentation sends me to the silly HTML button creator. I don't need hand-holding through the coding, I just need to know where I can find the proper documentation. I don't want Paypal buttons that send customers to a paypal cart page every time they add something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload

This is what I was looking for. It only took 3+ hours to find, so congrats to you Paypal. You've stolen my money in the past, now you've stolen my time. Hopefully this helps someone else who was looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I'm looking for a way to implement paypal in my java (spring) server so my clients (or I) can easily setup their webshops. I totally agree that implementing PayPal in a web application should be simple and in reality is a total mess.

So thanks a lot for posting this here, I guess you also saved me some additional time!

Best wishes,

Jochen